# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/STRY0017346' by x commits

Tags: git, git-flow

My workflow is as follows:

- git pull origin develop
- git flow feature start xyz
- < do some work here, drink lots of coffee >
- git commit -m "blabla"
- finally git flow feature finish xyz

This is what I did today, but when I try to finish my feature I get:

> Branches 'feature/STRY0017346' and 'origin/feature/STRY0017346' have
>   diverged. And local branch 'feature/STRY0017346' is ahead of
>   'origin/feature/STRY0017346'. Branches 'develop' and 'origin/develop'
>   have diverged. Fatal: And branch 'develop' may be fast-forwarded.

When I do `git status`

> On branch feature/STRY0017346 Your branch is ahead of
>   'origin/feature/STRY0017346' by 2 commits.   (use "git push" to
>   publish your local commits) nothing to commit, working directory clean

Very confusing and I am unsure how to resolve this. First time this happens to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by doing the following:

```
git checkout develop
```

Then

```
git pull origin develop
```

Finally I was able to finish my feature

```
git flow feature finish xzy
```